# How do I copy ExtJS 5 examples with sencha cmd?

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd, sencha-cmd5

I want to make a web app that is very similar to the extj5 portal example: http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/portal/index.html

I would like to copy it to a different directory and start coding.

Here are the steps I am taking:

1) Copy portal directory to my working directory.

2) Cd into portal

3) Run the following on the command line.

```
sencha app upgrade ext-5.0.0 // Ext 5 and this app should be in the same directory
```

But when I do so, I get:

```
$ sencha app upgrade ext-5.0.0
Sencha Cmd v5.0.2.270
[WRN] Did not locate framework package
[WRN] Failed to resolve package ext-theme-neptune
[WRN] Failed to resolve package sencha-charts
[ERR] Theme "ext-theme-neptune" not found
[ERR] Required package "ext-theme-neptune" not found
```

Any advice on the proper way to do this? Ruby is properly installed and I was able to successfully go through the extjs 5 tutorial (generate app, watch app, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha Cmd uses a lot of metadata, so your best bet is to generate a brand-new app in a blank folder first. Delete everything EXCEPT the `/.sencha/` folder.

Then copy/paste the portal example (everything EXCEPT the `/.sencha/` folder) into your new app.

You will also need to copy the `/examples/ux/` folder, and then update the `app.json` file -- pointing `classpath` to the correct `ux` folder.

---

Normally this process would be easier, but the Ext JS download is essentially a "workspace", so copying one of the examples into a new place will miss a lot of the workspace's assumed structure (namely, the framework!)

Comment: That was pretty much it. I had to keep the `ext` directory and the `packages` directory as well (from the initial app generation). Thanks!